# Adding pixelated menu button and language selector

Tags: html, css, svg

I tried to add a language selection and a pixelated menu button by importing a file in svg icon format. But I didn't manage to align both in the same line. I made another section where I added the primary navigation bar options and the logo. If someone could help me with the navigation bar by adding the language selector and the pixelated menu button, that would be great.

[image]

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=family=Source+Serif+Pro:wght@400;500;600');

html {font-size: 112.5%;} /*18px*/

body {
  margin: 0;
  background: #FAD9CC;
  font-family: 'Source Serif Pro', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.75;
  color: #000000;
}

header {
  background-color: #FAD9CC;
}
  
.container {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;

}

header::after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
  

.logo {
  float: left;
  padding: 20px 0;
  height: 40px;
}

nav {
  float: right;
}

nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

nav li {
  font-family: 'Neue Metana Next Variable';
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #000;
  display:inline-block;
  margin-left: 40px;
  padding-top: 24px;
  position: relative;
}

nav a {
  color: #444;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav a:hover {
  color: #000;
  font-weight: 500;
  
}

nav a::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #000;

  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 0%;

  transition: all ease-in-out 300ms;
}

nav a:hover::before{
  width: 100%;
}
  
p {
  
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  margin: 3rem 0 1.38rem;
  font-family: 'Neue Metana Next Variable', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 1.3;
}

h1 {
  margin-top: 0;
  font-size: 3.052rem;
}

h2 {font-size: 2.441rem;}

h3 {font-size: 1.953rem;}

h4 {font-size: 1.563rem;}

h5 {font-size: 1.25rem;}

h6 {font-size: 0.8rem;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Contactus</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header class="primary-header">
        <div class="container">
            <a href="#"><img src="Images/jeslogo-01.svg" alt="jeswin" class="logo"></img></a>
            <nav class="primary-navigation">
                <ul role="list" class="">
                    <li><a href="#">Who we are</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Success stories</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Blogs</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Careers</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>



    </header>
  
        <div class="container">
        <h1>Talk to us</h1>
        <p>Tell us all about your project right here, or send us an email at<br>
        project@spacecode.com and we will get back to you soon.</p>

        <form>
            <label for="fname">Name/Company: </label><br>
            <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br>
            <label for="lname">Email address:</label><br>
            <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname"><br>
            <label for="message">Drop us message:</label><br>
            <input type="text" id="message" name="message"><br><br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="confirm" name="confirm" value="conditions">
            <label for="confirm"> I agree to the <a href="#">terms and conditions.</a></label><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit request">
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to .container {} :

```
.container {
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}
```

What I would recommend is to rename the 2nd  to something like class="main-container" or class="container2". Then all you would need to do is write the style for that:

```
.main-container {
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Has partially worked! When I apply your css codes, other sections cause an alignment problem. Maybe you can copy the same code in my container class section in css to see the result

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. Sorry, I didn't see that there were two <div> containers with class="container".  I edited my answer to fix the issue you're having.

Comment: But there is still the same problem. I replaced the secondary container name with the one you suggested and have the same problem there. Maybe you can check it with codepen and edit it here.

https://codepen.io/jeswins/pen/MWVeOxW

Your pick:)

Comment: I just looked at the code, and I can definitely try to help out, but can you give me an idea of what the end result should look like? Maybe a photo or rough design of where you would like items to be displayed?